# LNK2019: unresolved external symbol but I have coded the function

Tags: c++, lnk2019

Can somebody help me with this? I'm using Visual Studio 2010
I'm getting this message and I don't know how to solve this.

> 1>  Generating Code...
>
> 1>dct.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public:
>   __thiscall Amostras::Amostras(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >)"
>   (??0Amostras@@QAE@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
>   referenced in function _main
>
> 1>C:\Users\redneck\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\dct\Debug\dct.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved
>   externals

Here is some of the *.cpp file:

```
class Amostras {
public:
    int original[10][257];
    int idct[10][257];
    float dct[10][257];
    int grupos;

Amostras::Amostras(void)
    {
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        this->original[i][0]=0; 
        this->dct[i][0]=0.0;
        this->idct[i][0]=0;
        }
        this->grupos=0;
    }

Amostras::Amostras(string arquivo)
{
    int n_samples=0,linha=0,coluna=0;
    int cont;
..
```

and here is the *.h

```
class Amostras {
public:
    int original[10][257];
    int idct[10][257];
    float dct[10][257];
    int grupos;

    Amostras::Amostras();
    Amostras::Amostras(string arquivo);
    void Amostras::mostra(void);
};
```

main

```
int main(void)
{
    Amostras *amostra = new Amostras("in.txt");
    dct(amostra,0);
    show(amostra,0);
    amostra->mostra();
    return 0;
}
```

hope it helps, i'm running out of options here :(

---

Solution:

So what I did was just putting the class just in *.h and then including the *.h in the class *.cpp that only has the methods and functions of that class. It worked!

Comment: See templatetypedef's answer, but if you want a more specific answer then post your code. In the meantime you can read this for more information on LNK2019: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

This linker error usually means that you have prototyped a function but forgotten to define it.  Make sure that you have implemented the function

```
Amostras::Amostras(string arg);
```

somewhere, and that when you were linking your code that the object file containing that implementation was linked in.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's the constructor of Amostras's class. And it didn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to define the `Amostras::Amostras(string arg);`
though declared in your *.h file

```
Amostras::Amostras(string arg)
{
}
```

copy the above code in your *.cpp file

OR

you can also do this by commenting the line from your *.h file.

```
//Amostras::Amostras(string arg);
```

whoa! do you have a *.h file ? if you are working in only *.cpp then lemme know.

Comment: I have and *.h file with all the prototypes from my *.cpp file.

Comment: ok, and did it worked ? try to make a inline constructor if you are not using it.

Comment: It didn't worked, i have all my class defined in *.cpp, with all constructors (2), variables, and just one function. In my *.h I have prototypes of the constructors, variables, and the function as well. I'm including in my other file the *.h.